# getting partial response for one single call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asynchronous

I am using dotnet 3.5 and AJAX and i want to get partial responses for my one single call given to server.

Its like I want to retrieve multiple profiles in one call and cannot let the system wait for all the profiles to get loaded.

Meanwhile all the profiles are loading in form of strips on the screen the user should be able to start working with the already loaded profiles.

eg
If I gave call to server and it returns 10 profiles in result then while displaying it one the screen I do not want the user to wait for all 10 profiles get loaded instead, he should be able to start working as soon as 1st profile loads and meanwhile rest 0 profiles loads on the screen.

Is it possible using Javascript, AJAX. IF yes, then how? Kindly help.

Thanks in Advance ^_^

Devshree

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible using AJAX.

The way the page would load would be as so:

- Page loads instantly with profile display area
- Ajax call requests profiles
- The server uses multiple [HttpResonse.Write()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1463ysyw.aspx) to return profiles which gets rendered on the broswer (as they're received by the browser)

The rendering element could be acheived through an update panel or even some jQuery for more fine-tined control.